# UWP - <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors> tag causes the app to crash at InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have resolved the issue but for better understanding I'm asking this question. In Debug mode, following app was crashing on the call to `InitializeComponent();` and was sending me to the last line of the file `App.g.i.cs` as shown below. After spending quite sometime as to why it's happening, I decided to remove the entire `<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>.....<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>` block from the `MainPage.xaml` file. And now it's compiling fine.

**Question**: Why the above block was causing the crash?

**MainPage.xaml**:

```
<Page
   x:Class="UWP_AccessFilesTrainingCrse.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   .....
   Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <providers:InteractiveProviderBehavior x:Name="MsalProvider" />
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

<Grid>
  <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>

</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**App.g.i.cs**:

```
............
..........
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

May you missed add clientId for `InteractiveProviderBehavior` class. For the testing it could work well in my side. And the following is used code.

```
<Page
    x:Class="EncryptFile.MainPage"

    ......
    xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:providers="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Providers"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <providers:InteractiveProviderBehavior x:Name="Provider" ClientId="Your_ClientId" />
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

For more detail please refer this [getting start](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Graph-Controls#-getting-started).